# Yellow Pages API Not Working Properly using Curl in php

Tags: php, curl

Works great, even just by typing it into the URL.

But now in my PHP script, when I build the URL it is not working.

Yellow pages API:

http://api2.yp.com/listings/v1/search?searchloc=91203&term=pizza&format=json&sort=distance&radius=5&listingcount=10&key=xxxxxxxxxx

Here is my code snippet

```
 $apiURL = 'http://api2.yp.com/listings/v1/search?searchloc=91203&term=pizza&format=json&sort=distance&radius=5&listingcount=10&key=xxxx';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$apiURL);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($data);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this **`cURL`** param.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
```

That is because you are getting 301 redirect from the URL. So you need to add it. [*Personally Tested*]